# Laravel-Livewire Issue polling foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

This is a livechat web app, I need to "refresh" when sending a message, poll works well when using now() outside the foreach (to comprobate that works), but inside the foreach the content and now() does nothing!! I need to refresh the browser to see the changes (the new message) and I dont know how to fix it...
[image: chatview]

I tried all in web tutorials and replicate it to, nothing works for me.

Comment: Depending on how you have your component setup, You can re-render the component using ``$this->render()`` in your ``save()`` method. Can you post the component code so someone can better assist you?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please avoid to share your code as image.

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct Livewire to run a certain function that the polling will call. Make sure that in that function your do a ->fresh() on the data you want to refresh.

Example:

```html
<div wire:poll="updateMessages">
    @foreach($userMessages as $userMessage)
      ...loop here...
    @endforeach
</div>
```

```php
public Collection $messages;

function updateMessages()
{
    $this->messages->fresh();
}
```